# SQL Pivoting data for sign in/sign out, by application

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have an audit log that stores events that occur on one or more connected applications in the whole system.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @staffID INT;

SET @staffID = 4;

SELECT 
    @startDate = dbo.Date(COALESCE(@startDate, DATEADD(day, -1, GETUTCDATE()))),
    @endDate = dbo.EndOfDay(COALESCE(@endDate, GETUTCDATE()))

SELECT
    l.RecordedOn, s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName + ' (#' + CAST(l.StaffIDAffected AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ')' AS StaffName,
    InOut = CASE WHEN (l.Type = 'AUS') THEN 'Sign In' WHEN (l.Type = 'AUSO') THEN 'Sign Out' END,
    a.Name AS ApplicationName, l.ApplicationID
FROM Logs l 
LEFT JOIN OtherDB.dbo.Staff s ON (s.ID = l.StaffIDAffected)
LEFT JOIN Applications a ON (l.ApplicationID = a.ID)
WHERE
    l.Type in ('AUS','AUSO') AND
    l.StaffIDAffected = @staffID AND
    l.RecordedOn BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
ORDER BY s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName, l.RecordedOn ASC
```

This returns the following data:

`RecordedOn              StaffName       InOut    ApplicationName
                                                        ApplicationID
2015-06-01 13:56:32.490 Joel Smith (#4) Sign In  NULL   0
2015-06-01 14:05:02.900 Joel Smith (#4) Sign In  NULL   0
2015-06-01 14:06:01.470 Joel Smith (#4) Sign Out NULL   0
2015-06-01 14:22:57.000 Joel Smith (#4) Sign In  NULL   0
2015-06-01 14:23:04.170 Joel Smith (#4) Sign In  NULL   0
2015-06-01 14:36:10.293 Joel Smith (#4) Sign In  NULL   0
2015-06-01 14:47:38.993 Joel Smith (#4) Sign In  NULL   0
2015-06-01 14:55:56.297 Joel Smith (#4) Sign In  Admin Website  4
2015-06-01 14:56:33.107 Joel Smith (#4) Sign In  Panel  2
2015-06-01 14:56:43.783 Joel Smith (#4) Sign Out NULL   0
2015-06-01 15:00:03.950 Joel Smith (#4) Sign In  Panel  2
2015-06-01 15:06:33.403 Joel Smith (#4) Sign In  Admin Website  4
2015-06-01 15:06:45.843 Joel Smith (#4) Sign Out Admin Website  4
2015-06-01 15:23:57.543 Joel Smith (#4) Sign In  Panel  2`

The format of what I want is below. I'm coalescing null Application Names to 'General' and coalescing null Application IDs to -1. (The NULL values will disappear over time, but for now they need to be handled somewhat gracefully).

`StaffName       ApplicationName ApplicationID SignIn     SignOut
Joel Smith (#4) General       -1 2015-06-01 13:56:32.490 NULL
Joel Smith (#4) General       -1 2015-06-01 14:05:02.900 2015-06-01 14:06:01.470
Joel Smith (#4) General       -1 2015-06-01 14:22:57.000 NULL
Joel Smith (#4) General       -1 2015-06-01 14:23:04.170 NULL
Joel Smith (#4) General       -1 2015-06-01 14:36:10.293 NULL
Joel Smith (#4) General       -1 2015-06-01 14:47:38.993 2015-06-01 14:56:43.783
Joel Smith (#4) Admin Website 4  2015-06-01 14:55:56.297 NULL
Joel Smith (#4) Panel         2  2015-06-01 14:56:33.107 NULL 
Joel Smith (#4) Panel         2  2015-06-01 15:00:03.950 NULL 
Joel Smith (#4) Admin Website 4  2015-06-01 15:06:33.403 2015-06-01 15:06:45.843
Joel Smith (#4) Panel         2  2015-06-01 15:23:57.543 NULL`

Note that it should separate login/logout times by Application Name/Application ID.

This is what I have so far, but it's missing **something**:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @staffID INT;

SET @staffID = 4;

SELECT 
    @startDate = dbo.Date(COALESCE(@startDate, DATEADD(day, -1, GETUTCDATE()))),
    @endDate = dbo.EndOfDay(COALESCE(@endDate, GETUTCDATE()))

SELECT
    StaffName,
    ApplicationName,
    ApplicationID,
    SignIn,
    SignOut
FROM 
( 
    SELECT
        l.RecordedOn, 
        s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName + ' (#' + CAST(l.StaffIDAffected AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ')' AS StaffName,
        InOut = CASE WHEN (l.Type = 'AUS') THEN 'SignIn' WHEN (l.Type = 'AUSO') THEN 'SignOut' END,
        COALESCE(a.Name, 'General') AS ApplicationName, 
        COALESCE(l.ApplicationID, -1) AS ApplicationID
    FROM Logs l 
    LEFT JOIN OtherDB.dbo.Staff s ON (s.ID = l.StaffIDAffected)
    LEFT JOIN Applications a ON (l.ApplicationID = a.ID)
    WHERE
        l.Type in ('AUS','AUSO') AND
        l.StaffIDAffected = @staffID AND
        l.RecordedOn BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    --ORDER BY s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName, l.RecordedOn ASC
) p
PIVOT
(
    MIN(RecordedOn)
    FOR InOut IN ([SignIn], [SignOut])
) pvt
```

This code returns the following data:

`StaffName   ApplicationName ApplicationID   SignIn  SignOut
Joel Smith (#4) Admin Website   4   2015-06-01 14:55:56.297 2015-06-01 15:06:45.843
Joel Smith (#4) General 0   2015-06-01 13:56:32.490 2015-06-01 14:06:01.470
Joel Smith (#4) Panel   2   2015-06-01 14:56:33.107 NULL`

What am I doing wrong? I'm using SQL Server 2012/2014.

**EDIT** I also tried without a pivot with interesting results:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @staffID INT;

SET @staffID = 4;

SELECT 
    @startDate = dbo.Date(COALESCE(@startDate, DATEADD(day, -1, GETUTCDATE()))),
    @endDate = dbo.EndOfDay(COALESCE(@endDate, GETUTCDATE()))


;WITH cte1 AS
(
    SELECT  *
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY StaffIDAffected, CAST(RecordedOn AS DATE) ORDER BY RecordedOn) 
                AS num
                ,CASE WHEN ([Type] = 'AUS') THEN 'Sign In' WHEN ([Type] = 'AUSO') THEN 'Sign Out' END AS [Status]
    FROM    Logs
    WHERE [Type] IN ('AUS','AUSO')
    AND StaffIDAffected = @staffID
    AND RecordedOn BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
)

SELECT  l1.StaffIDAffected
        , l1.RecordedOn [SignIn]
        , l2.RecordedOn [SignOut]
FROM    cte1 l1
left outer JOIN   
        cte1 l2 ON 
        l2.StaffIDAffected = l1.StaffIDAffected
AND     CAST(l2.RecordedOn AS DATE) = CAST(l1.RecordedOn AS DATE)
AND     l2.num = l1.num + 1
WHERE   l1.status = 'Sign In'
    AND (l2.Status IS NULL OR l2.Status = 'Sign Out')
```

Note that this one didn't include the Application, since I was just trying to get it to get the correct values with NULL application name/ID...

`4  2015-06-01 14:05:02.900 2015-06-01 14:06:01.470
4   2015-06-01 14:56:33.107 2015-06-01 14:56:43.783
4   2015-06-01 15:06:33.403 2015-06-01 15:06:45.843
4   2015-06-01 16:00:35.477 2015-06-01 16:01:47.703
4   2015-06-01 16:02:20.487 2015-06-01 16:03:34.827
4   2015-06-01 16:09:14.353 2015-06-01 16:09:22.213
4   2015-06-01 16:13:26.377 2015-06-01 16:14:01.560`

Comment: I tried not using a PIVOT but it looked like the logout time matched the next login time if I was expecting a NULL in that column. I've updated the answer to include this attempt.

Comment: Where's @bluefeet when you need him!? LOL

Comment: @StuartLC, yep, bluefeet is female. I feel smrt! The joke makes sense now. Nice booby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have no fiddle I can only suggest. Pivot will group by columns from subquery that are not in `aggregation` part and `spreading` part i.e. it will group by `StaffName, ApplicationName, ApplicationID`. So you will end up with several rows where there are distinct combinations of those columns.

Now it seams that you want all `login` rows with closest `logout` rows. If this is true then you can do something like this:

```
select c1.ApplicationID, 
       c1.ApplicationName, 
       c1.StaffName,
       c1.RecordedOn as SignIn,
       oa.RecordedOn as SignOut
from cte1 c1
outer apply( select top 1 RecordedOn from cte2 c2 
             where c1.ApplicationID = c2.ApplicationID and 
                   c1.StaffName = c2.StaffName and 
                   c2.RecordedOn > c1.RecordedOn and
                   c2.InOut = 'Sign Out' and
                   c1.num + 1 = c2.num
             order by c2.RecordedOn) oa
where c1.InOut = 'Sign In'
```

Comment: To keep it together, the query also needs `and c1.num + 1 = c2.num` added to it. This works because of the partitioning done by `ROW_NUMBER()`.